# ssh-add -l: error fetching identities: invalid format

Tags: ssh-agent

Despite `ssh-add` claiming my key was succesfully added, it was clear ssh-agent was not fowarding my keys: ssh from remote servers into a second remote serviers were not working;  `capitrano deploy` stoped working

The clue was the output: `error fetching identities: invalid format` when doing `ssh-add -l`

```
$ ssh-add ./id_2021
Enter passphrase for ./id_2021: 
Identity added: ./id_2021 (./id_2021)

$ ssh-add -l
error fetching identities: invalid format
```

I've tried making new keys but I still get this error.

Answer (score 2):

For reasons I can't explain, this worked:

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent); ssh-add 
Agent pid 23676
Enter passphrase for /home/david/.ssh/id_xyz: 
Identity added: /home/david/.ssh/id_xyz (/home/david/.ssh/id_xyz)

$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /home/david/.ssh/id_xyz (RSA)
```

The clue was in [this forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1776160#p1776160).